# Chrome extension which toggles On and Off

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, toggle

I'm trying to make an extension which would toggle another specific extension on and off. However, I tried over and over and didn't find a way to make it work.

Basically, my extension brings a popup with a on/off switch (a checkbox) and I need to make it so that it toggles another extension on and off...

Here's my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <p class="bb">Liga/Desliga do Banco do Brasil</p>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And popup.js

```
var bankId = "mkeabchhfifpaaoefpockjhaphjmoapp";

if(document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked != true)  {
                    chrome.management.setEnabled(bankId, false);


  } else if(document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked == true)
  {

                    chrome.management.setEnabled(bankId, true);

}
```

And manifest.json

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "48.png",
      "default_title": "Liga/Desliga o Bando Do Brasil",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "description": "Clique para ativar/desativar a extensão do BB",
   "icons": {
      "128": "128.png",
      "16": "16.png",
      "48": "48.png"
   },
   "name": "Toggle Banco Brasil On/Off",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "management" ],
   "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

You can check the extension "demo" here:   http://liveweave.com/8M4IvJ

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself. Only linking to the code is not acceptable.

Comment: What part isn't working?

Comment: Well, since popup.html works and the toggle doesn't, it is a scripting problem, therefore popup.js isn't doing its job, and I may also  need more files, like background.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how your extension currently works.

There's your popup page, that loads, with the checkbox unchecked by default.

Then, your code runs, checks if the checkbox is checked (it isn't) and disables the extension you specify.

And then.. *nothing*. You never told Chrome to do anything else. Your code finished running, there are no event listeners, so it's a static page now. Probably not what you wanted.

---

Now, let's fix it. First, I guess you want to set the initial state of the checkbox to the current state of the extension. Easy enough:

```
chrome.management.get(bankId, function(info) {
  // Gotta check if we got the info:
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // Something's not right; probably extension is not installed.
    // Warn the user somehow? (but no alert(), it can break the popup)
  }

  document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked = info.enabled;
});
```

Next up, we don't want the state checked when we open the popup. Instead, we want to hook to an event, specifically, whenever the value of the checkbox changes.

Again, easy enough:

```
document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  // You don't need the conditional if() {} else {}, just use the binary value
  chrome.management.setEnabled(bankId, this.checked);
});
```